# Convert std::list to cv::Mat in C++ using OpenCV

Tags: c++, list, opencv, mat, svd

I'm trying to solve an equation system using SVD: `cv::SVD::solveZ(A, x);`, but `A` needs to be a Matrix. OpenCV doesn't offer any convertion of a `std::list` to `cv::Mat`. So my question is, whether there is a smart way to convert it without having to convert the `std::list` to a `std::vector` before.

The Matrix `A` is a 3xN matrix. My list contains `N` `cv::Point3d` elements.

My code looks something like this:

```
std::list<cv::Point3d> points; // length: N
cv::Mat A = cv::Mat(points).reshape(1); // that's how I do it with a std::vector<cv::Point3d>
cv::Mat x;
cv::SVD::solveZ(A, x); // homogeneous linear equation system Ax = 0
```

If anybody has an idea about it, then please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cv::Mat` can handle only continously stored data, so there are no suitable conversion from `std::list`. But you can implement it by yourself, as follows:

```
std::list<cv::Point3d> points;
cv::Mat matPoints(points.size(), 1, CV_64FC3);
int i = 0;
for (auto &p : points) {
    matPoints.at<cv::Vec3d>(i++) = p;
}
matPoints = matPoints.reshape(1);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask: is matPoints a 3xN dimensional matrix (or at least treated as such by OpenCV)? If I write it like this, then matPoints has one row and N columns. This result in x having N rows and 1 columns. But x should be 1x3 afterwards...

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up rows and columns. I edited the answer. Now `matPoints` has (points.size()) rows and 3 columns. @jkl

Comment: Ah, ok. Cool. Thanks. I'm not that used in matrices including Vec3d elements. That's why I had to ask again.