# how to convert c++ std::list to Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv, std, mat

After accumulating the char * array in std :: list

I want to put all of it into Mat data.

EX)

Example.h

```
class ClassA
{
public:
   char message[9600];
   ...
   ... else variable

}
```

Example.cpp

```
while(true) {
   int length = recv(hSocket, message, sizeof(message) ,0);

   messList.push_back(message);
   if (messList.size() < 2) {
            continue;
   }

   // Here ...
   Mat matInputData(60, 80, CV_16UC1, ..?); <-- All data in the accumulated 'messList'

}
```

if

In cases like the above

The value of the first message is

message [0] = '1';
message [1] = '2';

... Other 9598 ...

.

The value of the second message

message [0] = '3';

message [1] = '4';

... Other 9598 ...

...

For the above example,

.

I have matInputData

'1', '2', 'remaining value' ...... '3', '4'

I want to be serialized.

Comment: what is Mat data?

Comment: The code you show have *undefined behavior*. You push a pointer to a (very) local variable into the list, the then the array `message` directly goes out of scope leaving you with a stray pointer that you can't use for anything. If the data is a string, then why don't use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)? Or if it's just a collection of characters without terminator, then how about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: Furthermore, please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And clarify your question and your problem in the *body* of the question.

Comment: Sorry. I will modify the contents of the article to make it easier to understand.

Comment: You can only pass an `array-like memory-continue buffer` to Mat, while list is not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert std::list to cv::Mat in C++ using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30478316/convert-stdlist-to-cvmat-in-c-using-opencv)